# Ruby tests with spec and capybara xml post

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, specifications

I am trying to figure out how to send a xml http request (validated by request.xhr?) using `page.driver.post()` method.

Have you any suggestions? Running out of ideas :(.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing XML http requests then you're doing API testing which you really shouldn't be using Capybara for.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, it is possible to pass it like this.

page.driver.post("/",{"HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH" => "XMLHttpRequest"})